# using xpath to tell selenium where to click?

Tags: python, xpath, selenium

I'm new to all of this but I've learned a few things about python not long time ago, could you help me specify the correct the XPath for selenium to click?

I've tried this way, but didn't work, obviously :(

```
self.selenium.click("xpath=//html/body/div/div/div/div[4]/ul/li[3]/a")
```

If you're wandering where did i get that ugly XPath, it's from Firebug's copy XPath option.

I think that the HTML snippet is as long as hell so i couldn't do more than this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="outer_wrapper">
      <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
          <div id="menunav">
            <ul>                                
              <li><a title="Login page" href="[dest]">Login</a></li>                              
              <li><a title="" href="[dest]">Sitemap</a></li>
              **<li><a title="" href="[dest]">Administration</a></li>**
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it would help if you give us the HTML that this works on

Comment: Is the HTML dynamically generated, such that the item you want to click changes each time?

Comment: @decebal: First, don't start your path with `//`, just `/` works. Second, is there a XHTML namespace declaration?

Comment: maybe my question is not straight enaught , i know how to extract an Xpath ,i just don't know how to use it with selenium

Comment: It might be easier to use: `//a[@href="http://..."]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below are a few example locators you could use to click the `Administration` link (based on your XPath and HTML snippet). The correct Selenium command is `click`.

- `link=Administration`
- `css=a:contains(Administration)`
- `css=#menunav a:nth-child(3)`
- `xpath=id('menunav')/descendant::a[3]`
- `//a[text()='Administration']`
- `//a[contains(text(), 'Administration')]`

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks dave, but i still don't get why you use the text() method that way, shouldn't be text('administration') ?

Comment: You're right that you don't need to use `contains` in this case. You can use `//a[text()='Administration']` instead.