# How to click on a given link?

Tags: python, selenium, click

```
<td class="button" nowrap align="center">  
    <a href="#" onKeyPress="javascript:checkkey(event);" onMouseDown="javascript:funclogin();">  
        Login  
    </a>  
</td>
```

How do i click this button using selenium in python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [using xpath to tell selenium where to click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406103/using-xpath-to-tell-selenium-where-to-click)

Comment: can you elaborate more on this

Answer (score 0):

What about using the class of the  tag ?

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='button']/a").click()
```

Anyhow, you may want to add a better identifier in the code to make this more robust.